# What’s the difference between EFI system partition and Ext4 journaling file system?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning

I’m trying to install Ubuntu in a computer and I’m not sure about the partitions, swap area mJFSfile system and Reserve BIOS boot area.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you are trying to install Ubuntu as a second system and concerned about how partitions work, then install Ubuntu as a Virtual Machine and leave partitions alone.

Answer (score 1):

The EFI system partition is used by UEFI:

> The EFI (Extensible Firmware Interface) system partition or ESP is a partition on a data storage device (usually a hard disk drive or solid-state drive) that is used by computers having the Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI). When a computer is booted, UEFI firmware loads files stored on the ESP to start installed operating systems and various utilities.

Ext4 is used by Linux:

> The ext4 journaling file system or fourth extended filesystem is a journaling file system for Linux, developed as the successor to ext3.